# How can I use sysdate in apache drill

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, apache, apache-drill

I want to run this query through Apache Drill.

```
select * from mytable where  my_date BETWEEN sysdate-1280 AND sysdate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from mytable 
where  my_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, interval '1280' day(4))
AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `current_date` instead of `sysdate`. See the docs about available time functions here: https://drill.apache.org/docs/date-time-functions-and-arithmetic/#other-date-and-time-functions

Comment: Ya. It'sworking.
Here is exact solution for my query.
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, interval '1280' day(4)) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP